# C# - Select query not working in SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have to select user name from a database in SQL Server. The query that is generated by `SqlCommand` works in SQL Server Management Studio but not in my code.

And this only happens when the input is like `AFFAQPC/affaq` containing `/`.

The code is:

```
public int? getid()
{
    SqlConnection Db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);

    Db.Open();

    // Searching for id in Users table from the logged in username
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 id FROM UsersLogin where username = '@user1';", Db);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user1", userName);
    string query = command.CommandText;

    foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
    {
        query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
    }

    Trace.WriteLine(query);

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("111");
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
            Trace.WriteLine(id);
            Db.Close();
            return id;
        }
    }

    Db.Close();
    return null;
}
```

The error occurs when input contains a `/`.

The query that is generated in `SqlCommand`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id 
FROM UsersLogin 
WHERE username = 'AFFAQPC\affaq';
```

Comment: You are not handling your [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects (such as `SqlConnection`) correctly.

Comment: In C# strings, the backslash is an escape character. If you're building this query in C#, and that's a string literal, then you'll want to use a "@" before the string to specify a literal string with no escaping: where username = @'AFFAQPC\affaq';

Comment: You haven't shown where the `userName` variable comes from.

Comment: what @pmbAustin said is correct  
additionally if  "@user1" is a string parameter you do not need enclose it with single quotes. You should  try: "SELECT TOP 1 id FROM UsersLogin where username = @user1;"

Comment: @DaniDev, for me it seems like PmbAustin was talking about declaring a string as literal in C#, which is not necessarily the same as passing a backslash inside a string that came from a file or whatever. Key question is what Mason asked.

Comment: userName variable comes from `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` and its  a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the single quotes from your query string

```
username = '@user1'
to
username = @user1
```

The "Parameter" should be WITHOUT the "@", just the name

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("user1", userName);
```

if the userName value is a string (confirming whatever your source is), that will be properly recognized when processed.  You do not need to explicitly quote-it.  Otherwise, the query is specifically looking for a user '@user1' which is probably why it is not returning what you expect.

I have NO idea why you are cycling through all parameters to assign the value...  the userName field should already be good to go without doing your foreach parameter check.

Comment: agree the first assertion, it is at user1 without quotes, but when calling AddWithValue, @userName, should work.

Comment: I was cycling through the parameters to generate a real query generated by sql command.